# ActiveAdmin HMABTM Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can I solve this error message?  I'm trying to create a new object and I'm receiving the below error message.

**Error Message:** `unknown attribute 'w_artisan_id' for ArtisanColour.`

If I remove `collection_colour_ids` from the ActiveAdmin Form, there is no longer an error, so I'm pretty positive it has something to do with joining model I've created call `artisan_colour`

Code is below.

```
ActiveAdmin.register WArtisan do

    # See permitted parameters documentation:
    # https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
    #
    permit_params :name, collection_colour_ids: []
    #


     form do |f|
        f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
        f.input :name
        f.input :collection_colour_ids, multiple: true, required: true, :label => 'Colours', :as => :check_boxes, :collection => CollectionColour.all.collect {|u| [u.colour_name, u.id]}


        f.actions
     end

    end
```

Models:

```
class ArtisanColour < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :collection_colour
    belongs_to :w_artisan
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :collection_colour
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :w_artisan
end


class CollectionColour < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :artisan_colours
    has_many :w_artisans, through: :artisan_colours 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :w_artisans
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :artisan_colours
end


class WArtisan < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :artisan_colours
    has_many :collection_colours, through: :artisan_colours
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :collection_colours
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :artisan_colours

    def self.listing
      order(created_at: :desc)
    end
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "artisan_colours", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "collection_colours_id"
    t.integer  "w_artisans_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
    t.index ["collection_colours_id"], name: "index_artisan_colours_on_collection_colours_id"
    t.index ["w_artisans_id"], name: "index_artisan_colours_on_w_artisans_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database migration is incorrect.

it should be

```
t.integer  "w_artisan_id"
```

not

```
t.integer  "w_artisans_id"
```

the foreign key field is singular by default.